# Is it possible to move a specific metal with a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Let's say we have three metals weighing $100 \;\text{g}$, A, B, and C. With the same distance from a magnet or magnetic field, is it possible to move specifically A or B or C without moving the other two? What changes need to be made if we want to make any of those moveable?

Comment: While I don't think it's quite what you're envisioning, [eddy-current sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Identification_of_metals) are used to distinguish between coins and slugs in some vending machines.  This phenomenon requires the metal (or the magnet) to be moving, though.

Comment: This is kinda too vague to say either way. Assuming you mean a magnetic metal and a static field, sure: you could glue the metal to a table, but you wouldn't be asking if that's what you meant. Non-magnetic metal? Can only move that with a non-static magnetic field, but how much force you put on each metal depends on how conductive the metal is. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The easiest way is to make the one you want to move out of iron and make the other two out of copper.

If the material of the masses is fixed beforehand then you may not be able to move any of them.

If all are made of the same material and all are magnetic then you still may be able to be selective by using the shape of the magnet’s field. At the smoothest it will be a dipole which may allow selection of one. If you made your magnet quadrupolar or higher then you could obtain more spatial selectivity.